# Jenkins slave not able to find dotnet

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, windows, builds, dotnet

When I check for dotnet version it is throwing an error

```
D:\jenkins\workspace\csharp-windows-test>dotnet --version 
17:58:06 System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
17:58:06 Parameter name: path1
17:58:06    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
17:58:06    at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.CliFolderPathCalculator.get_DotnetUserProfileFolderPath()
17:58:06    at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FirstTimeUseNoticeSentinel..ctor(CliFolderPathCalculator cliFolderPathCalculator)
17:58:06    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
17:58:06    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
17:58:06
```

but when I search for 'where' it shows the location

```
17:58:06 D:\jenkins\workspace\csharp-windows-test>where dotnet  
17:58:07 C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
```

This is causing build failures. Can someone suggest a best way to resolve this

Also I was able to execute the script on the machine directly without issues. This is only happening when called from Jenkins

Comment: What if you call the full path "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --version or "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --help? Do you get the same error?

Comment: Im getting same error `D:\jenkins\workspace\csharp-windows-test>"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" --version 
    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: path1
    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did `echo %USERPROFILE%` from Jenkins it returned null. So I had to 
manually set `USERPROFILE` value from Jenkins as environment variable. Also I had to set these

`APPDATA=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming`

`LOCALAPPDATA=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local`